# Регулярные выражения. Как вытащить строку?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строка в которой не меняется только середина (это знак --), конец (заканчивается каким-то годом, т.е. 4 цифры), ну и собственно начало (большая буква после точки и пробела). Как вытащить эту строку целиком, если размер и количество слов может быть какое угодно? Уже три часа голову ломаю.

Comment: Привидите пример строки что бы голову не ломать вчитываясь...

Comment: Drilling Commences at the Up Town Gold Project. GlobeNewswire -- August 4, 2017. VANCOUVER, British Columbia, Aug. 04, 2017 (GLOBE NEWSWIRE) -- Silver Range Resources Ltd. Нужно чтобы на выходе получилось "GlobeNewswire -- August 4, 2017"

Comment: до `--` могут быть только английские буквы и пробел? и после этого знака пробел?

Comment: Внесите пожалуйста в сам вопрос, не пойму где у вас строчка заканчивается и начинается, тут две строчки или одна.

Comment: До "--" могут быть только английский слова (количество их всегда разное), после "--" месяц число, год.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пока получилось как-то так:

```
([a-zA-Z ]+ -- .*?[0-9]{4}).?
```

https://regex101.com/r/ohNyDH/1

из строки

```
Drilling Commences at the Up Town Gold Project. GlobeNewswire sdf sdf sdf -- August 4, 2017. VANCOUVER, British Columbia, Aug. 04, 2017 (GLOBE NEWSWIRE) -- Silver Range Resources Ltd. Glosdfsdfs -- August 4, 2222.
```

получается

```
GlobeNewswire sdf sdf sdf -- August 4, 2017
Glosdfsdfs -- August 4, 2222
```

---

возможно надо сделать так:

```
([A-Z]+[a-zA-Z ]+ -- .*?[0-9]{4}).?    // ([A-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z ]+ -- .*?[0-9]{4}).?
```

то есть заглавную букву приписать  в начале